# Asp.net chart control IsValueShownAsLabel and label will display values with $ symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-charts

I have set **IsValueShownAsLabel** to true in asp.net chart control.
I am trying to show these visible lables as **$100.00** instead of showing only numerics like **100.00** or so.

Is there any way as I understand that only numerics can be visible as lables.

Comment: If you can get the value to be displayed, you can apply the currency formatting provided by String class, String.Format("Price: {0:C}",value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chartSeries.LabelFormat = "${0.00}";
```

solved my problem

Edit:
The most professional way with hints from prthrokz's comment to the question.

```
chartSeries.LabelFormat = "{0:C}";
```